# How do you determine a basis for eigenspace when given an eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A =
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & -5 & 2 \\
        4 & 7 & -2 \\
        -3 & -3 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A-3I_3$ =
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5 & -5 & 2 \\
        4 & 4 & -2 \\
        -3 & -3 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

rref of $A-I_3$ =
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

So that means
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -x_2\\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        = x_2
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
+
x_3
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Does that mean the basis of the eigenspace is

$
\begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1  \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0  \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$

I'm confused because the answer key has the basis for the eigenspace as just

$
\begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1  \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$

Why is the other one not included?

Comment: There are two rows with pivots, hence the matrix has rank 2 and its nullity—the dimension of the eigenspace—is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the row-reduced echelon form is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. That means, the equivalent system of linear equations is

$$x_1 + x_2 = 0$$

$$x_3 = 0$$

$$0 = 0$$

That means, $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -x_2 \\ x_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = x_2 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Thus, the basis is $\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg\}$.